Cant run RPC because of this error in validator.sh
keep getting this error message when I run the command
/home/sol/bin/validator.sh to start my node.
error: Found argument '--acount-index' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
Did you mean --account-index?
USAGE:
solana-validator --account-index ... --dynamic-port-range <MIN_PORT-MAX_PORT> --enable-cpi-and-log-storage --enable-rpc-bigtable-ledger-storage --enable-rpc-transaction-history --entrypoint HOST:PORT... --expected-genesis-hash  --gossip-port  --identity  --known-validator ... --ledger  --no-os-network-limits-test --no-port-check --no-voting --only-known-rpc --private-rpc --rpc-bind-address  --rpc-port  --vote-account 
For more information try --help
Heres my start up script:
#!/bin/bash
export RUST_BACKTRACE=1
export RUST_LOG=solana=info
export SOLANA_METRICS_CONFIG="host=https://metrics.solana.com:8086,db=mainnet-beta,u=mainnet-beta_write,p=password"
exec solana-validator 
--identity ~/validator-keypair.json 
--vote-account ~/vote-account-keypair.json 
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d 
--rpc-port 8899 
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8099 
--no-port-check 
--gossip-port 8001 
--no-os-network-limits-test 
--no-untrusted-rpc 
--no-voting 
--private-rpc 
--rpc-bind-address 123.456.789.00 
--enable-cpi-and-log-storage 
--enable-rpc-transaction-history 
--enable-rpc-bigtable-ledger-storage 
--acount-index program-id 
--account-index spl-token-owner 
--account-index spl-token-mint 
--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record 
--log ~/log/solana-validator.log 
--accounts /mt/accounts/solana-accounts 
--ledger /mt/ledger/validator-ledger 
--limit-ledger-size 1,099,511,627,776 
--geyser-plugin-config yellowstone-grpc-geyser/config.json 
--rpc-send-default-max-retries 30 
--rpc-send-service-max-retries 30 
--rpc-send-retry-ms 2000 
--rpc-threads 64 
--full-rpc-api 
--account-index-exclude-key kinxdEcpDQeHPEuQnqmUgtYykqKGVFq6CeVX51AHJq6 
--account-index-exclude-key metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s 
--minimal-snapshot-download-speed \ 625000000

You misspelled --account-index as --acount-index. Try changing the line:
 --acount-index program-id 

to
 --account-index program-id 

